# Component relocate after resize JFrame and right corner manually resizing via drag mouse

Tags: java, resize, listener

[image]

I have build this `JFrame` in NetBeans Swing Builder and added below `ComponentListener`.

```
this.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() 
{  
   public void componentResized(ComponentEvent evt) {

       //Get mainJPanel last Bounds after resizing
       Rectangle panelCurrentRec = new Rectangle();
       panelCurrentRec = mainJPanel.getBounds();

       //Calculate gained/losed how much vertical pixels
       int heightVariation = panelCurrentRec.height - panelOriginalHeight;

       //First set new vertical and horizontal bounds for below jtable and revalidate
       Rectangle rec = new Rectangle();
       rec = jScrollPane2.getBounds();
       jScrollPane2.setBounds(rec.x, rec.y+(heightVariation/2), mainJPanel.getWidth(), rec.height+(heightVariation/2));
       jScrollPane2.revalidate();

       //Second set new vertical and horizontal bounds for above jtable and revalidate
       rec = jScrollPane1.getBounds();
       jScrollPane1.setBounds(rec.x, rec.y, mainJPanel.getWidth(), rec.height+(heightVariation/2));
       jScrollPane1.revalidate();

    }

});
```

When i press `Maximize` of JFrame everythings fine. All gained space calculate correctly and two JTables get new `Y positioning` and expand itself wih half of gaining space and fill the screen.

But when i go to right corner of JFrame, hold and try manually resizing, `ComponentListener` fired too much. If i fastly drag and complete resizing everythings fine.

But sometimes (generally slowly dragging or long dragging) JTables not resized `vertically` and turn to original `Y position` looks like below. But `Horizontal resizing always working.

[image]

With a little drag on after problematic dragging resizing turn to normal again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Don't use a null layout.
2. Don't use setBounds(...).
3. Don't use a ComponentListener.
4. Do use layout managers. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. In your case it looks the tables are of equal size so the easiest would probably be to use a [Grid Layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html).

You may need to use multiple nested panels with different layout to get your desired effect.